# Is it possible to force an unlock on a OneDrive Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

Cloud document and editing is very convenient. However, occasionally, a file becomes locked and it is not possible to reach one team member that is locking it (it is not clear what action locked the file exactly).

Is it possible in OneDrive to force unlocking a file (even it if means loosing latest changes) ?

Picture of the problem:

[image]

Note: File is shared over multiple networks. Not inside one company. In cloud. (not on shared drive)

Comment: Not certain why this question was downvoted.  File locking with unavailable team members is a very common and work-stopping problem.  I won't put this into an answer because it's an application-specific problem, but Google Sheets has fewer collaboration problems.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible for OneDrive to unlock the file because OneDrive is not locking it.

The file is being locked by Excel because someone already has the file open. This is normal behavior. Your only option is to save a new copy or wait until the other person has closed the file.

To avoid this in the future, you can [use a shared workbook to collaborate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534). This allows multiple people to have the file open simultaneously.

Comment: this does not solve the cloud problem. (in 2 different companies, 2 continents)

Comment: Didn't know that at the time I answered. That may be an issue that Excel can not overcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an Excel file lock - and stay that way even after rebooting the systems that previously had it open. Tried clearing download cache - no help.

What did finally work was to **restore** a previous version, which deleted whatever was holding the current version open. Luckily in this case I'm not aware of changes that were lost!

Comment: Please be aware that the change is indeed lost, so take caution if you really wanted to restore to previous version!

Answer (score 0):

Had a OneDrive excel file lock in IOS although not in use by any user or device. I was was able to unlock by just loggin out and back in onedrive on the IOS device. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing an Excel file from OneDrive, when my computer rebooted due to Windows patches.  When I restarted I was locked out of the Excel file.

I simply re-logged out of OneDrive and then logged back in and then I was able to get into the file.  So, logging out must have cleared the lock since I was the same user.

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved by Co-Authoring - to cut to the chase - sharing your document via a OneDrive link. See the below for requirements
[How to co-author Excel spreadsheets on OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB)